# Forking a video stream with gstreamer

Tags: rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

BLUF: I'd like to fan out an RTSP video stream using gstreamer so multiple processes can use the gstreamer process as a source, and I'm having problems doing that with `tcpserversink`.

I have an IOT camera that serves the video over RTSP, so I can successfully capture video with e.g.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://camera:554/data \
    ! rtph264depay \
    ! h264parse \
    ! mp4mux \
    ! filesink location=/tmp/data.mp4
```

I'd like to be able to capture several videos simultaneously from the stream, with arbitrary start and stop times - for example, I might have a video that runs from 0-120, another from 40-80, another from 60-100. For reasons that are not clear, when I request too many simultaneous streams, the camera starts killing existing streams. My theory is that the camera's hardware can't handle multiple connections and is running into resource starvation issues. To get around this, I'd like my recording server to have a single process that is re-hosting the RTSP stream from the camera, and my asynchronous recorder processes can attach to that.

It would seem that the following would work for the server subprocess:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://camera:554/data \
    tcpserversink port=29000
```

and the following for the asynchronous recorder:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e tcpclientsrc port=29000 \
    ! rtph264depay \
    ! h264parse \
    ! mp4mux \
    ! filesink location=/tmp/data.mp4
```

But it don't. The specific error I'm seeing on my client process is

> ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPClientSrc:tcpclientsrc0: Internal data stream error.

The documentation for [tcpserversink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tcp/tcpserversink.html) seems to indicate that you can just attach any pipeline end there and you're fine. It seems this isn't the case. What am I missing?

Comment: This is a frame question: I've found a solution that does what I want and it goes around the use of tcpserver altogether. I'm cleaning up the solution and will post my findings later.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a ! after data "data ! tcpserversink port=29000"